# How dose colorscheme file working when python.vim file not exist?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, filetype-python

I deleted python.vim in ~./Vim/vim82/syntax directory, and define colorscheme.vim in ~./Vim/vim82/colors directory.

The colorscheme.vim contain this code

```
call <sid>hi('pythonNumber', s:cdLightGreen, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonFloat', s:cdLightGreen, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonString', s:cdOrange, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonClass', s:cdBlueGreen, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonComment', s:cdGreen, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonFunction', s:cdYellow, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonDecorator', s:cdYellow, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonStatement', s:cdBlue, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonStructure', s:cdRed, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonImport', s:cdPink, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonRepeat', s:cdPink, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonConditional', s:cdPink, {}, 'none', {})
call <sid>hi('pythonOperator', s:cdBlue, {}, 'none', {})
```

The code successfully applied in vim editor as filetype=python.
I wonder how bring the syntax highlight such as 'pythonOperator', 'pythonConditional' ... even though there is no python.vim in syntax directory.
These keywords are not brought from python.vim in syntax directory?

Comment: You can run `:verbose hi pythonOperator` to see where it was last set. In my case for example it shows `Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/python.vim line 283`.

Comment: That was because Plugin what I was installed before and contain syntax file...haha. Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: @hibernation Does that mean your question is now answered?

Comment: If the question has an answer, please post it. The code shown in the post is also not minimal, because it doesn't work without at least a definition for the `s:hi` function, which you might want to [edit] and add. Lastly, you might want to know that `:filter ,syntax/py, scriptnames` can show the syntax files starting `py` that have been loaded